# What sounds do animals make in Esperanto?

Tags: word-choice

The sounds the animals make are conventionalised in many languages. In German, dogs say "wau-wau", cats "miau", cows "muh", and donkeys "i-ah". Are there conventionalised animal sounds for Esperanto? Are there verbs like "to meow"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [here on Wikipedia](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopeoj_en_Esperanto#Bestoj). The article covers more than just animals but here is the animals section (translated to English, in the order they appear in the Wikipedia article):

> - Duck: Gik-gak
> - Donkey: I-a!
> - Bird: Kvivit!
> - Cow: Muu!
> - Toad: Kŭaks!
> - Horse: Heeeeeen!
> - Elelphant: Baahaha!
> - Dog: Boj!
> - Cat: Miaŭ!
> - Rooster: Kokeriko!
> - Crow: Grak!
> - Lion: Roooooor!
> - Wolf: Hauuuuuu!
> - Marsupilamiko: Huba! (Marsupilamikino uzas Hubi!.) -> I have no idea why this is here but it is [this thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsupilami).
> - Turkey: Glu-glu-glu
> - Frog: Kva kvak!
> - Sheep: Be-e-e!
> - Owl: Hu-hu!
> - Fox: Jelp!

Comment: Kajto did a song about frogs in a tub, and the frog sound they used was "kvavak, kvavak, kvak kvak kvak!" So I'm guessing "kva kvak" and "kvavak" are probably both acceptable variants.

Comment: This Wikipedia list does not provide any source. How can we check its validity? These words are not common. (By the way, I was only aware of 3 words of this list.)

Comment: Kaj kion diras la vulpo?

Answer (score 9):

It seems like some people use the noun of the animal + the verb "bleki".

For instance:

The cat is meowing = La kato katblekas.

It may be easier to say and remember but it does not give you a very colourful vocabulary.

You can find some animal sounds in the **Plena Manlibro de Esperanta Gramatiko** (PMEG):
http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/ekkrioj_sonimitoj/neoficialaj_ekkrioj.html

The cat is meowing = La kato miaŭas (or mjaŭas according to PMEG).
The cat meows "meow" = La kato miaŭas "miaŭ".

Here are a few other animal sounds:

For dogs: boji/**boj!**

For cows: muĝi/**mu!**

For donkeys: iai/**ia!**

For frogs: kvaki/**kvak!**

For ducks: gaki/**gik-gak!**

There's also a list on Wikipedia:
https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopeoj_en_Esperanto

You can find some more on this page of the *Dictionnaire Français-Espéranto* by Roger Léger and André Albault:
http://www.ipernity.com/doc/bernardo/4878141/in/keyword/405548/self

Answer (score 3):

Antaŭ nelonge Paŭlo Moĵajev kunmetis similan liston: [La listeto de
bestoblekaj sonimitoj](http://mevamevo.livejournal.com/400078.html).

Mi tradukis nomojn de bestoj el la rusia:

> - Ŝafoj: be-be
> - Hundoj: boj-boj, baŭ-baŭ, vaf! vaŭ-vaŭ
> - Cikadoj kaj aliaj knalantaj insektoj: ĉirp-ĉirp, ĉir-ĉir
> - Anasoj kaj anseroj: gik-gak
> - Meleagroj: glu-glu-glu
> - Kornikoj: grak-grak, gra!
> - Griloj: grinc-grinc, gri-gri, ĉirp-ĉirp
> - Graŭlo de hundoj, grandaj rabobestoj: grrrr
> - Porkoj kaj aproj: grunt-grunt
> - Ĉevableko: hen-hen
> - Simioj: hu! hu!
> - Strigoj kaj gufoj: hu-hu! uhu! ulu! ululu!
> - Hurlo de hundoj kaj lupoj: huu! hauuuuuu!
> - Azenoj: iaaaa!
> - Cikonioj: klak-klak
> - Klukado de kokinoj: kluk-kluk-kluk
> - Virkokoj: kokeriko!  kikeriko!
> - Kverado de kolomboj: kurre-kurre, kver-kver, mur-mur-mur
> - Kriĉo de rabobirdoj (mevoj, agloj, akcipitroj ka): kriĉ-kriĉ, kri-kri
> - Kukoloj: ku-ku
> - Kvakado de ranoj kaj bufoj: kva-va! kva-kva! kvak! kŭaks-kŭaks-brekekeks!
> - Vaneloj: kvik-kvik
> - Hirundoj: kvit-kvit
> - Pepado de malgrandaj birdoj (paseroj, kanarioj ka): kvivit-kvivit, pep-pep
> - Kaproj: mek-mek
> - Miaŭo de katoj: miaŭ!
> - Ronronado de katoj: mur-mur
> - Bovoj: mu, muuu
> - Musoj, anseridoj: pip-pip! pi-pi-pi
> - Manĝserĉantaj kokinoj: put-put-put
> - Roro de grandaj rabobestoj (leonoj, tigroj ka): ror! roar!
> - Ŝuŝado de serpentoj: sss
> - La sono de flugo de muŝoj aŭ kuloj: zzzzzzzzzz
> - Zumado de abeloj, vespoj aŭ burdoj: zum-zum

Answer (score 2):

All I know is that cows "muĝas : mu!"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gh9w7QpyQtY

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  Everyone probably knows what sound cows make due to that video, haha.

Comment: I love that video (indeed I worked on the Russian subtitles), but I'm afraid your answer is incomplete so I'm downvoting it.