# What is the equivalent of "bleki" for snakes?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you describe that a snake is doing "*hiss hiss hiss*"?

Answer (score 10):

Laŭ [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#serpento):

> *serpento siblas*

Kaj la difino de [sibli](http://vortaro.net/#sibli) estas:

> **1** Eligi sonon similan al longedaŭra «s»: *vi iom siblas, vi havas en la buŝo unu denton, kiu fajfas<sup>Z</sup>; la serpento, abelaro siblas<sup>B</sup>;* (analoge) *la vento siblas en la kamentubon<sup>Z</sup>; siblantaj sagoj<sup>Z</sup>; la musfraŭlinoj sibladis k paroletadis<sup>Z</sup>.*

Se vi demandas pri la sono (onomatopeo), bedaŭrinde mi ne povas respondi.

Answer (score 4):

De PIV:

sibl/i (ntr)

1. Eligi sonon similan al longedaŭra «s»: vi iom siblas, vi havas en la buŝo unu denton, kiu fajfas <sup>Z</sup> ; la serpento, abelaro siblas<sup>B</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The verb meaning 'to hiss' is *sibli*. The usual way to imitate the hissing sound of a snake is "sss". This is used for example in the song [Katoj, katoj](https://familioj.wikispaces.com/Katoj,+Katoj) (sung a lot at events for Esperanto-speaking children), and is also mentioned in [the list of Esperanto animal sounds](http://mevamevo.livejournal.com/400078.html) compiled by Paŭlo Moĵajevo.

Comment: Mi tradukis la liston de Paŭlo Moĵajev en tiu [respondo](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/1410/465).

Answer (score 1):

Kiel aliaj respondantoj diris, sibli estas la vorto por la ago ke serpentoj faras, sed por la sono mi supozas ke oni povus diri komike "sssi"